# A error 'io.netty.channel.ChannelException: connection refused' when i use LocalServerChannel/LocalChannel？

Tags: java, netty

**server code：**

```
    public void server() throws InterruptedException {
    final EchoServerHandler serverHandler = new EchoServerHandler();
    EventLoopGroup group = new DefaultEventLoop();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(group, group)
                .channel(LocalServerChannel.class)
                .localAddress(new LocalAddress("foo"))
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<LocalChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(LocalChannel ch) {
                        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                        pipeline.addLast(serverHandler);
                    }
                });
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.bind().sync();
        System.out.println(EchoServer.class.getName() + "--started and listening for connections on--" + channelFuture.channel().localAddress());
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();

    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
    }
}
```

**client code：**

```
    public void client() throws InterruptedException {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(group)
                .channel(LocalChannel.class)
                .remoteAddress(new LocalAddress("foo"))
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<LocalChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(LocalChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new EchoClientHandler());
                    }
                });
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.connect().sync();
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
    }
}
```

**and the error：**

```
Exception in thread "main" io.netty.channel.ChannelException: connection refused
at io.netty.channel.local.LocalChannel$LocalUnsafe.connect(LocalChannel.java:375)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1245)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeConnectNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:118)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeConnect(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:238)
at io.netty.channel.PausableChannelEventExecutor.invokeConnect(PausableChannelEventExecutor.java:107)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:493)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:487)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1018)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:241)
at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$3.run(Bootstrap.java:230)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:328)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1412)
at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:280)
at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:877)
at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1706)
at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1661)
at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:126)
```

I glance over some relevant information on google and github,but has no answer,l look some example and copy it,but error still.came near to a breakdown...
  This is the first time I've been here to ask a question.

Comment: There is a good chance that this is a firewall issue. Disable your firewall on both the client and server as a quick test, then if that fixes it you can add a rule to allow traffic on those ports.

Comment: Is this in the same JVM instance ?

Comment: Yes,I run it on the same computer.